st_linemerge unable to sew simple multilinestring
The query below is resulting in some unexpected behaviour where st_linemerge seems to be unable to merge a simple Multilinestring.
select site, st_astext(trace), st_astext(st_linemerge(trace)) from mytable




site
trace
st_linemerge




"site1"
"MULTILINESTRING ZM ((122.76 -31.60 316.51 13,122.76 -31.60 309.51 20))"
"GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY"


"site2"
"MULTILINESTRING ZM ((115.57 -28.10 28.42 257,115.57 -28.10 27.48 258))"
"LINESTRING Z (115.57 -28.10 28.42,115.57 -28.10 27.48)"



Postgres v14.1,
Postgis v3.2
The Postgis docs mention an empty geometrycollection is returned when st_linemerge is used for anything other than a Multilinestring or Linestring. In the given example both input geometries are Multilinestrings and have the same shape (single line with a single start and endpoint) and I cannot see the reason why the function is working in one case but not the other.
